# R: Assign data frame column with POSIXct collection

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, posixct

I have a collection of [posixct](/questions/tagged/posixct) elements (I know I cannot keep the collection of the `POSIXct` objects as a vector, that is why I used `list` in this example):

```
input_timestamps <- list(
  as.POSIXct("02.08.2018", format = "%d.%m.%Y", origin = "01.01.1970", tz = "UTC"),
  as.POSIXct("04.08.2018", format = "%d.%m.%Y", origin = "01.01.1970", tz = "UTC"),
  as.POSIXct("14.08.2018", format = "%d.%m.%Y", origin = "01.01.1970", tz = "UTC")
)
```

Now I need to add this list as a column to a `data.frame`. 
The current solution is the following:

*1. convert the `POSIXct` objects to numeric and the list to vector*

`inputs_timestamps  <- unlist(lapply(input_timestamps, as.numeric))`

*2 - add this vector to `data.frame` as `POSIXct` object*

```
inputs_df <- data.frame(timestamp = as.POSIXct(input_timestamps, format = "%d.%m.%Y", origin = "01.01.1970", tz = "UTC"), input = 1:3)
```

I believe there could be a better way to do that. Please, share your experience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of two step process, it can be converted to vector with `do.call(`c``

```
inputs_df <- data.frame(timestamp = do.call(c, input_timestamps), 
                            input = seq_along(input_timestamps))
```

---

Or another option is change the `list` to a named `list` and `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
melt(setNames(input_timestamps, seq_along(input_timestamps)))
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know I cannot keep the collection of the POSIXct objects as a
>   vector, that is why I used list in this example

I don't believe this is true, take the following:

```
> input_timestamps <- c('02.08.2018', '04.08.2018', '14.08.2018')
> inputs_df <- data.frame(timestamp = as.POSIXct(input_timestamps, format = "%d.%m.%Y", tz = "UTC"), input = 1:3)
> class(inputs_df$timestamp)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> inputs_df
   timestamp input
1 2018-08-02     1
2 2018-08-04     2
3 2018-08-14     3


> input_timestamps <- as.POSIXct(c('02.08.2018', '04.08.2018', '14.08.2018'), format = "%d.%m.%Y", origin = "01.01.1970", tz = "UTC")
> inputs_df <- data.frame(timestamp = input_timestamps, input = 1:3)
> class(inputs_df$timestamp)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> inputs_df
   timestamp input
1 2018-08-02     1
2 2018-08-04     2
3 2018-08-14     3
```

In either case you can simply create a data.frame using a vector without the unnecessary conversions between.

**UPDATE**

If you already have them stored as individual objects, you can do the following.

```
input_timestamp1 <- as.POSIXct("02.08.2018", format = "%d.%m.%Y", origin = "01.01.1970", tz = "UTC")
input_timestamp2 <- as.POSIXct("04.08.2018", format = "%d.%m.%Y", origin = "01.01.1970", tz = "UTC")
input_timestamp3 <- as.POSIXct("14.08.2018", format = "%d.%m.%Y", origin = "01.01.1970", tz = "UTC")

input_timestamps <- c(input_timestamp1, input_timestamp2, input_timestamp3)
```

OR

```
input_timestamps <- c(
  as.POSIXct("02.08.2018", format = "%d.%m.%Y", origin = "01.01.1970", tz = "UTC"),
  as.POSIXct("04.08.2018", format = "%d.%m.%Y", origin = "01.01.1970", tz = "UTC"),
  as.POSIXct("14.08.2018", format = "%d.%m.%Y", origin = "01.01.1970", tz = "UTC")
)
```

Comment: Sorry if the initial post was misleading.
In your example this collection is assigned with the vector of string variables. But what if I already have some `POSIXct` variables, and now I want to put them into one collection so that would be possible to insert this collection into the `data.frame`?

Comment: Instead of storing them in a `list`, simply store them in a `vector`. If they are already stored in a list, then follow @akrun's example using `do.call` method.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to store `POSIXct` in a `vector`, but if then I `print(input_timestamps)` I get the worng date and time - timezone is wrong. I initialize the dates with "UTC" timezone, but when checking the vector it is "EEST". And it doesn't happen to the `list`, so that was the reason to use it.

Comment: This has something to do with `c()` stripping away the `tzone` attribute on a POSIXct, which then defaults to whatever you computer is. You can overcome this by `print(input_timestamps, tz = 'UTC)` or `attributes(input_timestamps)$tzone <- 'UTC'`